# After Installation of Ubuntu, VMware now not showing it, why?

Tags: vmware

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 Bit on this VMware 9.0 Workstation and it ran well 2-3 times but now when I run VMWare workstation or player, it's not showing Ubuntu.

[image]

[image]

Where has Ubuntu gone?

Comment: I don't use VMware, but can't you click in 'Open a Virtual Machine' then point to the directory/file where the virtual machine is?

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> to bring up the Library pane on the left in VMware Workstation (not in the player). It'll look like this:

[image]

The highlighted part shows the pane I refer to.

If you don't see any VMs listed:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to **Open** (to be found in the **File** menu)

Navigate to the directory with the VM files and choose the `.vmx` file (should be the only one shown)

[image]

Now click the **Open** button and the VM should be added to your Library.

Also in the preferences you can choose where VMware looks for VMs by default:

[image]